# IF statement needs to be repeated

Tags: excel, if-statement, automation, excel-formula

I created an If statement which does the following:

If A1's dropdown =" accepted" then the amount on b2 (A fee) will appear in cell c2, otherwise nothing happens.

I need this formula to add up the fee's as they get accepted. Meaning, if A1 - A5 got accepted then all the fees are calculated. Lets say the fees are $10 the formal will sum up the fee from B1-B5 that total (based off of my example) would be $50, therefore $50 should appear in C2.

The formula works (see below). The only thing is that this spreadsheet has 300 columns A1 - A300 and has the potential to grow even more. I am repeating the formula manually (see below).

Is there an easier way to do this so that I can have excel automatically add the formula as we create new columns?

```basic
=IF(January5 = "accepted", Fee5) +
 IF(January6 = "accepted", Fee6) +
 IF(January7 = "accepted", Fee7) +
 IF(January8 = "accepted", Fee8) +
 IF(January9 = "accepted", Fee9) +
 IF(January10 = "accepted", Fee10) +
 IF(January11 = "accepted", Fee11) +
 IF(January12 = "accepted", Fee12) +
 IF(January13 = "accepted", Fee13) +
 IF(January14 = "accepted", Fee14) +
 IF(January15 = "accepted", Fee15) +
 IF(January16 = "accepted", Fee16) +
 IF(January17 = "accepted", Fee17) +
 IF(January18 = "accepted", Fee18) +
 IF(January19 = "accepted", Fee19) +
 IF(January20 = "accepted", Fee20) +
 IF(January21 = "accepted", Fee21) +
 IF(January22 = "accepted", Fee22) +
 IF(January23 = "accepted", Fee23) +
 IF(January24 = "accepted", Fee24) +
 IF(January25 = "accepted", Fee25) +
 IF(January26 = "accepted", Fee26) +
 IF(January27 = "accepted", Fee27) +
 IF(January28 = "accepted", Fee28) +
 IF(January29 = "accepted", Fee29) +
 IF(January30 = "accepted", Fee30) +
 IF(January31 = "accepted", Fee31) +
 IF(January32 = "accepted", Fee32) +
 IF(January33 = "accepted", Fee33) +
 IF(January34 = "accepted", Fee34) +
 IF(January35 = "accepted", Fee35) +
 IF(January36 = "accepted", Fee36) +
 IF(January37 = "accepted", Fee37) +
 IF(January38 = "accepted", Fee38) +
 IF(January39 = "accepted", Fee39) +
 IF(January40 = "accepted", Fee40) +
 IF(January41 = "accepted", Fee41) +
 IF(January42 = "accepted", Fee42) +
 IF(January43 = "accepted", Fee43) +
 IF(January44 = "accepted", Fee44) +
 IF(January45 = "accepted", Fee45) +
 IF(January46 = "accepted", Fee46) +
 IF(January47 = "accepted", Fee47) +
 IF(January48 = "accepted", Fee48) +
 IF(January49 = "accepted", Fee49) +
 IF(January50 = "accepted", Fee50) +
 IF(January51 = "accepted", Fee51) +
 IF(January52 = "accepted", Fee52) +
 IF(January53 = "accepted", Fee53) +
 IF(January54 = "accepted", Fee54) +
 IF(January55 = "accepted", Fee55) +
 IF(January56 = "accepted", Fee56) +
 IF(January57 = "accepted", Fee57) +
 IF(January58 = "accepted", Fee58) +
 IF(January59 = "accepted", Fee59) +
 IF(January60 = "accepted", Fee60) +
 IF(January61 = "accepted", Fee61) +
 IF(January62 = "accepted", Fee62) +
 IF(January63 = "accepted", Fee63) +
 IF(January64 = "accepted", Fee64) +
 IF(January65 = "accepted", Fee65)
```

Comment: Woah that's hard to read. Please break up you question into paragraphs, and format your code.

Comment: I tried =SUMIF(A:A,"accepted",B:B). The sUm equals 0. Should be $40 Being that 4 cells were marked accepted

Answer (score 0):

How about a SUMIF formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"accepted",B:B)
```

This will sum all values from column B that show "accepted" in column A.

Here is what I am assuming your table looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried =SUMIF(A:A,"accepted",B:B). The sum equals 0. Should be $40 Being that 4 cells were marked accepted

Comment: Strange, would you be able to upload a screenshot of a sample data set? I am very surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: Please see the attached dropbox link to the images I dont know how to add it to this thread.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/71cybn48fpuc8t8/AADTknWUvYoNbj_ek2KXvRqya?dl=0

Comment: When I click on the link, I get an error. I have uploaded a picture into my answer of what I think your data looks like. My suggested formula is in field C7.

Comment: You are absolutely right , I realized the problem. The accepted option is in a Dropbox with other options such as declined and hold. So I ran the formula without a Dropbox and it worked. Then I ran it again with the Dropbox which caused the 0.

Comment: I updated my sheet to use a dropdown menu as well (see new picture in my answer) and the formula still works. Maybe it has to do with the way you set up the [dropdown menu .](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b)

Comment: I selected data validation>Allow:List >added the source which i placed on E500.

Comment: Then try =SUMIF(A:A,E500,B:B)